# When exiting terminal rawmode my contents stays on the screen

Tags: c, terminal

I've used this small editor for the basis of my project that I'm doing: https://github.com/antirez/kilo

The editor uses the terminal in rawmode and writes using VT100 escape sequences, however when exiting the program the contents that were displayed, stay displayed.
Before exiting...
[image: Before exiting]

After exiting...
[image: After exiting]

As you can see the prompt appears again but what was left of the editor stays there until written over.

```
// Low level terminal handling
 void disable_raw_mode(int fd)
{
        // dont bother checking the return value as its too late
        if (Editor.rawmode) {
                tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
                Editor.rawmode = 0;
        }
}


void editor_at_exit(void) 
{
        disable_raw_mode(STDIN_FILENO);
}

int enable_raw_mode(int fd) 
{
        struct termios raw;

        if(Editor.rawmode) return 0; //already enabled
        if(!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) goto fatal;
        atexit(editor_at_exit);
        if(tcgetattr(fd, &orig_termios) == -1) goto fatal;

        raw = orig_termios; // modify the original mode
        /* input modes: no break, no CR to NL, no parity check, no strip char,
         *      * no start/stop output control. */
        raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);

        // output modes - disable post processing
        raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);

        //control modes - set 8 bit chars
        raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);

        //local modes, choing off, canonical off, no extended functions, no signal chars (, etc)
        raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);

        //control chars - set return condition: min number of bytes and a timer
        raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; // return each byte, or zero for a timeout
        raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 1; //100ms timeout

        //put terminal in raw mode after flushing
        if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &raw) < 0) goto fatal;
        Editor.rawmode = 1;
        return 0;

fatal:
        errno = ENOTTY;
        return -1;
}
```

From what I understand, when the program exits the `atexit(editor_at_exit)` function is called and in that function raw mode is disabled. What am I missing to clean the terminal back to what it was before the editor was opened. I'm not looking to just `clear` the whole terminal.

Comment: This maybe https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Copy

Comment: what isn't it resetting except for clearing the screen? you're doing a `tcsetattr` with the original terminal settings - does that not work?

Comment: @ChrisTurner so the full screen mode of the editor stays up after exit, even though I use `tcsetattr` with `&orig_termios`.

Comment: expand the function: `editor_at_exit()` to output the terminal escape sequence to clear the screen

Comment: @CaseyWilliams that sounds more like something as described in the answer below is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @user3629249 I don't really want to clear the whole terminal screen, just reset it to its previous state before launching the editor

Comment: @ChrisTurner Okay, the answer below seems pretty logical so when I can, I'll write those escape sequences in and see what happens. Cheers!

Comment: @CaseyWilliams that does assume that you're doing escape sequences to put the terminal into that state in the first place tho?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I was wondering that... I'm using escape sequences for everything else so I'll just replace my enable and disable with the two escape sequences and see what happens, currently not at home so cant make the changes. Feel free to fork and have a go though! https://github.com/shnupta/bric

Comment: Changing the terminal settings does not change what is displayed on the terminal. Think of the termios settings as communications configuration. To control what is displayed, we use ANSI etc. control codes, written to the terminal (typically standard input); and because standard input is intended as read-only in C, we normally use POSIX low-level I/O functions (`read()`, `write()`) to do that. OP already has the terminal settings done; all they need to add is the clearing or temporarily switching to alternate buffer, by writing to the terminal, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Thank you again, makes perfect sense now!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is called *"alternate screen buffer"*, which originated in `xterm` but is nowadays supported by most terminals.

Alternate screen buffer is designed to provide exactly this functionality for full-screen terminal programs. In normal operation, output gets added to the scrollback buffer (and most terminals let the user scroll back to previous lines). Switching to the alternate screen buffer the scrollback buffer is left alone, and alternate screen buffer output is not added to the scrollback buffer. When returning from alternate screen buffer, the original scrollback buffer state is restored. This is what full-screen applications like `nano` use.

To switch to the alternate screen buffer, I recommend writing (the C string)

      `"\033[?1049h\033[2J\033[H"` (15 chars)
to the terminal. If the terminal emulator supports the alternate screen buffer, this changes to it, clearing it and moving the cursor to the upper left corner. If the terminal emulator does not support it, this will clear the screen and move the cursor to the upper left corner.

To return from the alternate screen buffer, I recommend writing (the C string)

      `"\033[2J\033[H\033[?1049l"` (15 chars)
to the terminal. If the terminal emulator supports the alternate screen buffer, this first clears the alternate screen buffer, then returns to the original scrollback buffer (like e.g. `nano` does). If the terminal emulator does not support it, this will clear the screen and move the cursor to the upper left corner.

I recommend this pair (`"\033[?1049h\033[2J\033[H"` and `"\033[2J\033[H\033[?1049l"`), because it works in a reasonable fashion regardless of whether the terminal emulator supports the alternate screen buffer or not, not leaving the full-screen application state visible afterwards.

If standard input is a terminal, I also recommend using e.g.

```
int write_term(const char *p)
{
    const char *q = p;
    ssize_t     n;
    int         retval = 0, saved_errno;

    /* Nothing to write? */        
    if (!q || !*q)
        return 0;

    saved_errno = errno;

    /* async-signal safe version of q = p + strlen(p) */
    while (*q)
        q++;

    while (p < q) {
        n = write(STDIN_FILENO, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > 0) {
            p += n;
        } else
        if (n != -1) {
            retval = EIO;
            break;
        } else
        if (errno != EINTR && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
            retval = errno;
            break;
        }
    }

    errno = saved_errno;
    return retval;
}
```

to write the strings to the terminal, because standard C I/O functions may not be able to write to standard input (which is intended for reading only, after all). The above function is extremely careful, ignoring signal delivery (and even busy-looping if necessary if standard input is nonblocking), and even keeping `errno` intact; it is also async-signal safe, which means it could be used in a signal handler safely (although I advise against changing terminal buffer mode or settings in a signal handler, as that gets quite complicated to do correctly).

(The OP's code might have a suitable low-level I/O function already implemented, but one was not shown in the question.)

Comment: Would you recommend keeping my existing `enable_raw_mode` and `disable_raw_mode` or can these be replaced entirely with just writing the two escape sequences you talked about?

Comment: @CaseyWilliams: I would keep your existing functions, adding the equivalent of `write_term("\033[?1049h\033[2J\033[H");` at/near the end of `enable_raw_mode()`; and `write_term("\033[2J\033[H\033[?1049l");` to `disable_raw_mode()` inside the if clause in `disable_raw_mode()`.

Comment: @CaseyWilliams: Looking at the github sources, you should change `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` to `isatty(fd)` and add `write(fd, "\033[?1049h\033[2J\033[H", 15);` in/to `enable_raw_mode()`; and add `write(fd, "\033[2J\033[H\033[?1049l", 15);` inside the if clause in `disable_raw_mode()`, to keep to the "kilo" coding style.